# How to start large cluster in reasonable time?

Tags: cassandra

I have to start a large cassandra cluster and starting one node at a time will be painful. I don't want to set `cassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false` permanently but is there a way to set it only for the first start.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to wait and do manually intended node start, I'd suggest using a automation tool like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) and code yourself boring actions (like sequential restart of cassandra nodes).